# Why is Jenkins triggering IVY build even though no SVN change?

Tags: svn, jenkins, ivy

I have a Jenkins job which polls SVN every five minutes for changes.  I am seeing weird behaviour whereby even when the log clearly states there are no SCM changes since the last poll.  Jenkins parses the individual ivy.xml files and each of the build.xml files are called.  The build files then compile the code already checked out in the Jenkins workspace and then subsequently publish a 1.0-snapshot jar artefact to IVY.  This is basically publishing an identical snapshot to IVY.  Trying to understand why Jenkins proceeds to parse the ivy files even though no SCM change has been detected.

The log output for the job is shown below.

```
   Started by user anonymous
   [EnvInject] - Loading node environment variables.
   Building in workspace C:\Software\Jenkins\workspace\Snapshots
   Updating svn://*****/Project1 at revision '2016-08-04T09:04:38.318 +0100'
   At revision 3570
   Updating svn://*****/Project2 at revision '2016-08-04T09:04:38.318 +0100'
   At revision 3570
   Updating svn://*****/Project3 at revision '2016-08-04T09:04:38.318 +0100'
   At revision 3570
   Updating svn://*****/Project4 at revision '2016-08-04T09:04:38.318 +0100'
   At revision 3570
   Updating svn://*****/Project5 at revision '2016-08-04T09:04:38.318 +0100'
   At revision 3570
   Updating svn://*****/Project6 at revision '2016-08-04T09:04:38.318 +0100'
   At revision 3570
   Updating svn://*****/Project7 at revision '2016-08-04T09:04:38.318 +0100'
   At revision 3570
   Updating svn://*****/Project8 at revision '2016-08-04T09:04:38.318 +0100'
   At revision 3570
   Updating svn://*****/Project9 at revision '2016-08-04T09:04:38.318 +0100'
   At revision 3570
   no change for svn://*****/Project1 since the previous build
   no change for svn://*****/Project2 since the previous build
   no change for svn://*****/Project3 since the previous build
   no change for svn://*****/Project4 since the previous build
   no change for svn://*****/Project5 since the previous build
   no change for svn://*****/Project6 since the previous build
   no change for svn://*****/Project7 since the previous build
   no change for svn://*****/Project8 since the previous build
   no change for svn://*****/Project9 since the previous build
   Parsing Ivy Descriptor Files
   Triggering com.****:ivy1
   Triggering com.****:ivy2
   Triggering .....

   Finished: SUCCESS
```

Any pointers welcomed.

Comment: please check your build trigger configuration of the job. you should use 'poll scm' settings

Comment: My build trigger is 'poll scm', but it still triggers even though no SVN changes were detected since the last build ran.

Comment: so you should check the SVN checkout configuration since it seems that something is wrong there.

Comment: The scm part seems fine, I am more confused as to how the IVY trigger plugin deduces which ivy.xml files from those it has found from the checkout should be triggered.  The build log file is very sparse and just contains a random list.  I would have expected it to have detected the src code change and then used the ivy.xml file that sits in the same directory as the root of the src folder and used that as the starting point.

Answer (score 0):

Started by User "Anonymous"
Can you confirm that there are security settings and not everyone is able to manually trigger the build. "Anonymous" indicates that someone is manually triggering the build.

Comment: Why would a manual build be any different to an scm poll trigger.  I would expect a manually triggered build to also detect no SCM change and therefore no need to proceed parsing the ivy.xml files?

Comment: Manually triggered build is not checking for SVM changes.

Comment: Seems to me that Jenkins IVY plugin is triggering random ivy files.  I made a test change to a file and checked it into SVN.  The Jenkins log detects the change, but then proceeds to trigger a set of ivy build for other modules.  it never actually built the module that was linked to the checked in file.